# Advantages and disadvantages of using testNG for keyword driven selenium webdriver framework?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have developed keyword driven selenium webdriver framework. But I am in doubt whether to go to user testNG or not?.If not using testNG how can I generate the test report? Now I am printing the result in master excel file containing the testcase ID,webdriver actions etc.
Any suggestions please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is better that you use TestNG , It has following advantages :

1. It generate logs
2. You can do parallel testing
3. Annotations  helps to set program/function priority easy
4. Allow to generate HTML report of execution
5. You can group test cases
6. You can set test cases priorities.
7. You can do data Parameterization

TestNG really makes automation testing easy.

Still it is depends on you and your actual requirement. No need to use TESTNG if you do not want to prioritize your tests and do not want to use annotation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can we do the parallel testing?

Comment: If you are familiar with testNG , then you can create XML for your java classes and then can specify "tests=parallel" so it will run all your tests parallel.   For more detail please check : http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same dilemma as the OP is facing. TestNG requires some code to be developed for a test case while a keyword framework works towards eliminating this coding. There is usually a driver script in keyword frameworks and one possible way to use testing is to write the driver method in @Test and include only the driver class in testng xml. This way same set of test cases can be executed for multiple browsers. However, TestNG reports won't be useful here and customized reporting might be required. Hope this helps.