# When to use keyword driven frame work and TestNG in selenium automation

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have implemented few test scenarios on Facebook using selenium keyword driven framework. I could do it properly by using other plugins like Apache POI, log4j etc..
After each test case I am updating the result(PASS/FAIL) as well in the excel sheet.

Here, I am not able understand what is specific significance of TestNG as we are able to automate and produce the results as well using framework.

So when to use the frameworks and when to use the TestNG. 
Appreciate any help.

Comment: I see this question as possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342942/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-testng-for-keyword-driven-selenium-webdriv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342942/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-testng-for-keyword-driven-selenium-webdriv)

Answer (score 0):

On TestNG: 
I use TestNG for reporting purposes. It auto generates a report on the test cases ran with pass/failed. You can then customize those reports fairly easily to suit your needs.

Another handy point on using TestNG is test annotations, especially if you're using the Page Object Model. Example can be seen here. http://www.ontestautomation.com/using-the-page-object-model-pattern-in-selenium-testng-tests/

You can also use TestNG annotations to run your test cases in a particular order.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG is powerful JAVA unit testing framework. It has incomparable features of:

- Parallel execution
- Data-Driven testing
- Run configuration through XML/YAML
- Listeners
- and lot more...

In addition to standard TestNG report, there are [other reporting extensions](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#reporters) also available. If you want to use keyword driven or behavior driven approach you can opt for TestNG extension like [QAF](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#frameworks).

To be brief, rather than spending time and effort in reinventing the wheel, one should start using proven solution, if available.